# Desktop.getDesktop().open(file) doesn't work when jar is running in background as windows service

Tags: java, file, windows-services

As the title, when my jar is running in the background as a windows service, `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)` does not work(I configured `-Djava.awt.headless=false`). It works fine if I run the jar in the foreground as `java -jar`

Please how can I solve this problem, or there is a better API to replace it (API needs to be compatible with mac and windows), thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` return true?  If so, does `Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)` return true?

Comment: @VGR Thank you for your reply. Yes, they all return true, but when the jar is running in the background as a windows service, there is no response or exception when executing `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`

Comment: From (very bad memory), window services are run as different user (this could be inaccurate) and are not attached to the current desktop, so opening windows isn’t possible (again, it’s been a really long time since I’ve needed to do anything like this, so the explanation may be somewhat inaccurate)

Comment: Try [specifying a regular user account on the Log On tab](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService) and let us know if that helps or not.

Comment: @CoreTech Thank you for your reply. I tried logging in but it still doesn't work.